# XSLT beginner query

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few similar XML structures, which I want to be able to process properly in XSLT, so users can view online.

The first:

```
<TABLETYPE TYPEABBRV="MTHPRTSTS" TOTALINDICATOR="N">
      <CATEGORY TYPE="DISABSTATUS" VALUE="WDIS" />
      <STATUS>MET</STATUS> 
   </TABLETYPE>
```

The next:

```
<TABLETYPE TYPEABBRV="ELEMIDADNIND">
  <STATUS>METADDIND</STATUS>
</TABLETYPE>
```

What I'd like to do is make sure when "STATUS" is displayed I don't get the value from both by checking for the existence of "CATEGORY". If "CATEGORY" exists, output one block of code. If not, a different block. I know I should use "xsl:choose" and "xsl:when" but can't figure out how to test if "CATEGORY" exists. Thank you in advance for viewing and answering. I should add that these 2 blocks of XML are in separate files.

After reading the first answer, I realized I should perhaps clarify further. The goal is to output what is between "STATUS".

I found a way to rearrange and change code using the answer below for a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to test if "CATEGORY" exists

```
test="CATEGORY"
```

will return true if `CATEGORY` exists. More precisely - since XSLT is very much context-dependent - it will return true if the current node has a child element named "CATEGORY". So if you are in the context of `TABLETYPE`, then:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="CATEGORY">
        <xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY/@TYPE"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="STATUS"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

should work for you.